# $2^y = 5, 5^x = 2$,$xy = ?$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function

$$2^y = 5$$ $$ 5^x = 2$$
$$xy = ?$$

Indeed, I could find the $x$ and $y$ by using logarithm. However, I don't want to do it with that way. Let me show my thinkings:

$$5^x \cdot 2^y = 10$$

Here we get

$$xy = 10$$

It seems wrong on my textbook, why?

My Kindest Regards!

Comment: Just take $log$ from both!

Comment: @MehrdadZandigohar log needs to be calculated by a calculator

Comment: Yes, of course. I answered for more clarification. @AndrewLi

Comment: We do not need to calculate it. It is only used to take down $x$ and $y$ from power to get $xy$. So don't feel bad about taking log... @Goendo

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an approach without using logs:
$$
5^{xy} = \left(5^x\right)^y = 2^y = 5
$$
so $xy=1$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $\;5 = 2^y = (5^x)^y = 5^{xy},$.

Comment: didn't get your hint.

Comment: @Goendo You get $5^{xy}=5^1$, so $xy=\ldots$

Comment: Where do we get $5^{xy}$ we only have $5^x$.

Comment: @Goendo At step 2 you replace $2$ with $5^x$, then in step 3 use that $(a^b)^c=a^{bc}$.

Answer (score 1):

$$ 2^x = 5 = 2^{1\over y}$$ so $x ={1\over y}$...

Answer (score 0):

Don't feel bad about taking $ln$ because it is simple and also does not need the calculator you mentioned:

$2^y = 5 \to \ln(2^y)=\log(5) \to y\ln(2)=\ln(5) \to y=\dfrac{\ln(5)}{\ln(2)}$

$5^x = 2 \to \ln(5^x)=\ln(2) \to x\ln(5)=\ln(2) \to x=\dfrac{\ln(2)}{\ln(5)}$

$x \cdot y =\dfrac{\ln(5)}{\ln(2)} \cdot \dfrac{\ln(2)}{\ln(5)}=1$

Answer (score 0):

Given that $ 2^{y} = 5 $, $$ 5^{x} = (2^{y})^{x} = 2^{yx} = 2^{xy} = 2$$

Solving $ 2^{xy} = 2 $ for $xy$:
$$ \log(2^{xy}) = xy\log(2) = \log(2)$$ or
$$ xy =1$$